# Add an object to an array using redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

everyone. I want to store an Object into an array using redux toolkit. Unfortunately, it is the case that a new object is not added, but simply replaced. How can I change this behavior ?

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
 warenkorb: [],
 preis: 0,
 bewertung: 0,
};

export const produktSlice = createSlice({
name: "produkt",
initialState,

reducers: {
hinzufügen: (state, action) => {

  // Also not work
  // state.warenkorb.push(action.payload);
  //

  state.warenkorb.push([...state.warenkorb, action.payload]);
  state.preis += action.payload.preis * action.payload.anzahl;
},
entfernen: (state, action) => {
  if (state.warenkorb.includes(action.payload)) {
    state.warenkorb.splice(
      state.warenkorb.findIndex((id) => id === action.payload),
      1
    );
  }
},
bewerten: (state, action) => {
  state.bewertung = action.payload.bewertung;
 },
 },
});

export const { hinzufügen, entfernen, bewerten } = produktSlice.actions;

export default produktSlice.reducer;
```

As you can see, a new call is started each time with the new object
[image]

And if I look at it with the help of the debugger, I get to see this. Why the first two objects and why do they look like this?
[image]

Comment: You want to replace or just append ?

Comment: I want to append new objects

Comment: I assume in this entfernen reducer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not push into the state you should replace the current state with a whole new state to ensure state updates

The code should be:

```js
hinzufügen: (state, action) => {

  state.warenkorb = [...state.warenkorb, action.payload];
  
}
```

I made this  [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-liskov-w633u9?file=/src/App.js) for the total working example

Comment: Thx. But also didn't work

Comment: @Captai-N please check the sandbox example i added